# Highlighting Jekyll Itself

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid, github-flavored-markdown

I want to write {{ site.url }} on the code snippet of my Jekyll blog. But unfortunately it shows my `username.github.io` in the code snippet. How can I avoid this problem and show {{ site.url }} in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid Jekyll processing a template tag surround it with `{%raw%}..{%endraw%}`, for example:

```
{% raw %}
~~~ liquid
{{ site.url }}
~~~
{% endraw %}
```

> Raw temporarily disables tag processing. This is useful for generating
>   content (eg, Mustache, Handlebars) which uses conflicting syntax.

Comment: Thank you . { % raw % } {{ site.url }} {% entae %} was enough for me...